# How do you align logo with navbar on left and prevent text from hiding behind navbar?

Tags: html, css

I'm a complete newbie to HTML and CSS but my university has linked tutorials on LinkedIn Learning. Yet I still find myself stuck often. Currently, I'm working on making a website for my university assignment but I'm having difficulties. I would like to place the logo above the "About Us" link on the navbar but I'm not sure how to. I would also like to align the text so that it's not hidden behind the navbar. I'm a complete newbie to HTML and CSS but my university has linked tutorials on LinkedIn Learning. Yet I still find myself stuck often. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}



.logo-img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 10px; /* Adjust this to your menu item height */
  width: 50px; 
  height: 50px;
}


.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 130px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #F5F5DC;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}



.sidenav a {
  padding: 50px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #DEB887;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}



h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 191, 128);
}

.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("img_parallax.jpg");

  /* Set a specific height */
  height: 500px;

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta name="description" content="Second Slice Café website">
  <title>Second Slice Café</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">

  <style> 
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Questrial&display=swap');

    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&display=swap');      
  </style>  
</head>
<body>

<div class="logo-img">
  <a href=""><img src="images/Green.png" alt="Second Slice Café"></a>
</div>

<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about us">About Us</a>
  <a href="#menu">Menu</a>
  <a href="#zero waste">Zero Waste</a>
  <a href="#our partners">Our Partners</a>
  <a href="#faqs">FAQs</a>
  <a href="#contact us">Contact Us</a>
</div>
<h1>Welcome to Second Slice Café!</h1>



<article>
  <section>
    <h2>About Us</h2>
    <p>Our story begins way back when with husband Trevor and wife Naomi. We shared a passion for brewing the perfect cup of coffee from scratch using only pure coffee beans. We would even bring family and friends over to judge whose coffee was better. That's when it hit us. Why not share our love of organic coffee with the world? Thus we decided to launch our own café in the suburbs of Northcote in 2015. Since then, we've branched out into baked goods, sandwiches and milkshakes.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Menu</h2>
    <p></p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Zero Waste</h2>
    <p></p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Our Partners</h2>
    <p></p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>FAQs</h2>
    <p><b>Q: Are there any vegan options at Second Slice?</b></p>
    <p><i>A: Of course! For our coffee, we offer almond milk, soy milk, rice milk, oat milk and hemp milk. We also offer a select menu for our vegan customers.</i></p>

    <p><b>Do you have gluten-free and lactose-free items?</b>
  <i></i>
  </p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <p></p>
  </section>
</article>

<body>
</html>
```

Comment: honestly the best way I've found how to do this would be, to go to a site that has the navbar you're looking for and then inspect the code.  From there you can see the exact styling and layout that they use for all of their elements in their navbar.

Answer (score 0):

You should just reduce the width of the main component if you want them to be side by side or up the `z-index` if you want one element to be on top of another element

```
.logo {
    z-index: 10; //It'll be on top of everything else
}
.main-container {
    width: 90vw; //viewport width (basically 90% of screen width)

.sidebar {
    width: 10vw;
}
```

Hope you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Add position: absolute; and z-index: 2; to class logo-img.

```
    .logo-img {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        line-height: 1px; /* Adjust this to your menu item height */
        width: 50px; 
        height: 50px;
    }
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}



.logo-img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1px; /* Adjust this to your menu item height */
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;
}


.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 130px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #F5F5DC;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}



.sidenav a {
  padding: 50px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #DEB887;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}



h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 191, 128);
}

.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("img_parallax.jpg");

  /* Set a specific height */
  height: 500px;

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
      <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="description" content="Second Slice Café website">
    <title>Second Slice Café</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
    
          <style> 
          @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Questrial&display=swap');

                @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&display=swap');   
         </style>  
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="logo-img">
     <a href=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="Second Slice Café"></a>
       </div>
    
    <div class="sidenav">
          <a href="#about us">About Us</a>
          <a href="#menu">Menu</a>
          <a href="#zero waste">Zero Waste</a>
          <a href="#our partners">Our Partners</a>
    <a href="#faqs">FAQs</a>
    <a href="#contact us">Contact Us</a>
   </div>
    <h1>Welcome to Second Slice Café!</h1>
    
   
    
    <article>
    <section>
    <h2>About Us</h2>
    <p>Our story begins way back when with husband Trevor and wife Naomi. We shared a passion for brewing the perfect cup of coffee from scratch using only pure coffee beans. We would even bring family and friends over to judge whose coffee was better. That's when it hit us. Why not share our love of organic coffee with the world? Thus we decided to launch our own café in the suburbs of Northcote in 2015. Since then, we've branched out into baked goods, sandwiches and milkshakes.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
    <h2>Menu</h2>
    <p></p>
    </section>
    <section>
    <h2>Zero Waste</h2>
    <p></p>
    </section>
    <section>
    <h2>Our Partners</h2>
    <p></p>
    </section>
    <section>
    <h2>FAQs</h2>
    <p><b>Q: Are there any vegan options at Second Slice?</b></p>
    <p><i>A: Of course! For our coffee, we offer almond milk, soy milk, rice milk, oat milk and hemp milk. We also offer a select menu for our vegan customers.</i></p>
    
    <p><b>Do you have gluten-free and lactose-free items?</b>
    <i></i>
    </p>
    </section>
    <section>
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <p></p>
    </section>
    </article>
    
    <body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are sever ways to achieve it.... simplest being:- Just put a div container inside "sidenav" as sibling of About us link and put image tag inside with required scr where your logo is stored.

```
<div class="sidenav">
    <div class="logo" height="50" width="100">
       <img src="{logo src should here}" alt="logo" />
    </div>
    <a href="#about us">About Us</a>
    ...........
    ......
</div>
```

Comment: I tried editing the code but now it looks like the logo is too big to be seen. I have to scroll down to view the links in the sidenav bar.

Comment: It's because you didn't put height="50" width="50" in your div container which is holding the img tag. Also, plz reduce the font-size of your Nav links i. e. anchor tags.

Comment: Um, I changed it now but the image is still too big. I reduced the font size in CSS but there was no change.

Comment: Here you go:-
.sidenav a {
  padding: 20px 8px 6px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

and:- 
 <div class="logo" height="50" width="50">
       <img src="{logo src should here}" alt="logo" />
   </div>